# Python: 100 connections to MongoDB cause a high cpu usage, Why?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

MongoEngine support connect to multi mongodb databases.

I write this simple code that make 100 connections to mongodb from python script

[image]

But, I noticed in the `top` ,
Python cause a very high CPU usage

[image]

My CPU:

[image]

Why this ?

And If i wanna connect to multi mongodb database in python,
How to  do it correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an equivalent script using pymongo, and the DB CPU usage stayed at 0 even with 300+ connections open.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

for x in xrange(100):
    MongoClient()
```

Try it out and see if the problem persists? I believe that it's the officially supported Python package for MongoDB.

Comment: pymongo has a built-in connection pool, so, using pymongo is OK.

Comment: You need to store the clients in a list, otherwise they lose the reference and get destroyed immediately after creation.

Comment: Yes, I did that when I did the test, this code just shows how to create 100 connections with pymongo. The results are still the same.